# Does calling aspell give better results than matching against it's word-list dump?

Tags: aspell

When implementing a spell checker as an external process, I can call aspell directly, however this has the overhead of starting a process.

An alternative solution is to dump all `aspell` words to a list, eg:

```
aspell -d en_US dump master
```

If I only need to know if the word is correctly spelled or not, and ignoring details about case sensitivity. Is there any difference between checking a word exists in the word-list, and calling aspell directly?

---

For example, if I'm writing software which includes a spell checker, would it be reasonable to load all words into a `set` data-structure, then check if the set contains a word - as an alternative to calling `aspell`.

Comment: I'm asking if aspell is doing anything besides matching against a word-list (ignoring case conversion).

Comment: Okay, but if I'm only checking for valid spelling (e.g. underlining misspelled words)